# R swirl() course Getting and Cleaning Data lesson 2: Grouping and Chaining with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, swirl

I'm in the swirl() course, Getting and Cleaning Data: swirl Lesson 2: Grouping and Chaining with dplyr, I receive an error when submitting the summarize1.R script. The script I'm submitting is identical to here:

```
pack_sum <- summarize(by_package,
                      count = n(),
                      unique = n_distinct(ip_id),
                      countries = n_distinct(country),
                      avg_bytes = mean(size))
```

The resulting error is:
"Error : object '' not found"

I'm using R version 3.6.1, on Windows 10, with {dplyr} version 0.8.4, and {swirl} version 2.4.5.

Thank you!
Natya

Comment: Please use a small reproduciible example

Comment: I don't think your by_package is doing anythin here.. have you tried pack_sum <- group_by(by_package) %>% summarize(count = n(),

Comment: @Dr. Flow: I have tried your code but the similar error message still appeared. Thank for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem a while ago, the problem is in count=n(), try the following:

```
pack_sum <- summarize(by_package,
                  count = sum(n()),
                  unique = n_distinct(ip_id),
                  countries = n_distinct(country),
                  avg_bytes = mean(size))
```